# JTable Database connectivity

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I am developing an application in which I used the `JTable`. My table has two fields on is `id` and the second is `name`. When the user enter some data into table I want to put that into database.

The sample of my code is given below.

```
DefaultTableModel T = new DefaultTableModel();
try{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO JTableExample (id,name)VALUES (?,?)";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    table_emp.setModel(T);
    pst.execute();

    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: ..what is your *question?*

Comment: I want to connect my jTable with database i can insert the record into database using jTextfiled etc. but i have no idea that how save the data into database using jTable please help me if you can thanks

Comment: Note for future: *"How to save the data into database using jTable?"*  **Is** a ***question.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect example as per your need

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/

Also do close the  connection and also share the exception if you are getting any.

Comment: Thanks but the above example is about to save record into database using jText fields my problem is jTable. I want to save data into database using jTable but i hava no idea. please help me if you can do. thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151123/how-to-save-edited-jtable-data-to-database   use this link i hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that I am not familiar with database , but I think You need to override DefaultTableModel's method setValueAt to something like this

```
 public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    User rowObject = dataList.get(row);
    switch(column){
        case 0: rowObject.id = (String)aValue;break;
        case 1: rowObject.name = (String)aValue;break;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a sample code for saving data into database using a jTable. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: eh..I have a sample code to saving data to local file..I haven't learn database yet..

Comment: I think you might achieve this by saving the information you need to get the object from database in the model's data vector.

Answer (score 0):

i just googled how to use database , and here is my code , might have something wrong..
for example you use your id to identify your data

```
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
String id = getVauleAt(row,0);
super.setValueAt(aValue,row,column);
switch(column){
   case 0:
      sqlStr = "//changes you need";break;
   case 1:
      sqlStr = "//changes you need";break;
}
  pst=con.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
   pst.executeUpdate(sqlStr);}
```